# Unable to hear emitted events

Tags: events

I'm using Infura as my provider. From what I've read online, it seems that using a websocket with infura instead of http is the first step to being able to hear events however I only get an empty list when I retrieve all the latest events

I have a script that causes the contract to emit an event every 20 seconds.

This is what I'm using to test hearing events

```
    events = contract_ws.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock="latest", toBlock="pending").get_all_entries()
    if (len(events) != 0):
        break
    else:
        print("Not yet.")
        time.sleep(3)
```

But it never breaks out of the loop so therefore never hears an event. What am I missing?

I'm using the web3py library but I don't think that'll effect the solution.

Comment: 1. "It seems that if I have as long as I use websocket instead of http provider than I should be able to here events".

Comment: 2. "But it never hears an event".

Comment: Please resolve the conflict between these two opposite statement!

Comment: I updated the question to be more clear. From what I've read online, it seems that it is impossible to hear events with an http provider and should be possible with a websocket, however I've yet to hear any events.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the connection type. Think about it - why would this layer in the communication protocol have any impact whatsoever on what type of data is provided in a (much) higher layer?

Comment: History (i.e., events in your case) is provided or not, according to what the node owner has decided. For example, infura has recently decided to limit historical data on all of its nodes (perhaps unless you purchase a subscription or something; I haven't tried that, but I would imagine that it might be the case).